# Parent Function name of a nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the parent function name of a nested function. I'm using the jquery ajaxComplete methode, in there I'll get the outer function name:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, settings){
 // this shows me only the success function of the ajax call, 
 // but I need the outermost function
 alert(settings.success.toString()); 
}
```

Many thanks for your support!

Comment: Which outer function? The anonymous callback? `ajaxComplete()`? Or something even outside of that?

Comment: No, you never really need the name of a function. Tell us what you'd want to do with it…

Comment: There's never even a guarantee that a function **has** a name.  I think you're out of luck.

Comment: It sounds like you want to get the name of the function that contains the actual `$.ajax` call. Is that correct? Besides, don't you want the actual function perhaps?

Comment: @pimvdb: Oh, you're right. I need exactly the function which calls the $.ajax request. How can I get this function in ajaxComplete?

Comment: On my Web app are datatables, calendars,.... This all are loadad asynchron with jquery ajax. With modal dialoges users are able to edit/add/delete datas on these components asynchronus. After done, the specific component need to be refreshed. So, I react on the ajaxcomplete methode where I wish to refresh the component by calling the initial function again.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to get the function that originally invoked the AJAX method. However, `.ajaxComplete` receives the settings argument from the `$.ajax` call. You could require that all your AJAX callers include something like:

```
caller: <theirname>,
```

in the settings. jQuery should ignore this extra option, but it will be passed along to you.